# Power BI: Missing Option to Toggle On Slider

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to reproduce the same dashboard. I'm working on the same computer with two iterations of Power BI open. One iteration (the original dashboard) has the slider option. The other iteration of Power BI doesn't. Screenshots below.

Iteration #1

[image: Drop down includes "between"]

[image: Able to toggle on "slider"]

[image: This is what I'd like to reproduce]

Iteration #2

[image: No option to toggle on "slider"]

[image: No option to select "between"]

This is driving me nuts. What am I missing???

I had trouble turning the slider option on last time, but somehow managed to do it. Not sure what I'm overlooking this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type of the column should be continuous e.g. number or date.